# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, response

I'm trying to link the frontend and the backend on localhost.
Backend running on ASP.NET Development Server under localhost:19993.
Frontend running on localhost:4200. It is Angular CLI.

In angular i'm using folowing method:

```
private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:19993/api/SearchForm';

getSearchResultTable(hash: string): Promise<Array<ResultTableCardViewModel>> {
         return this.baseService.get<Array<ResultTableCardViewModel>>(this.apiUrl);
}
```

following method from `baseService`:

```
public get<T>(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Promise<T> {
    return this.http.get(url, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as T);
}
```

But on request i see folowing error:

[image]

I added proxy.conf.json to the root folder, which contains the following:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:19993",
      "secure": false
    }
}
```

Also package.json settings: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`.
But it is not fixed  this issue. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?,

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?